# can't connect to localhost from other pc

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I have made a maven web application, now i want to host it locally with tomcat so that other people within the same LAN can test it.

My ip adress is static and i have forwarded port 80, but if anyone other than me types in the static ip adress followed by the project name that is in the webapps folder it just can't seem to find the web page. 
I've seen many things on the internet like windows firewall could block the connection and i tried to fix it but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions that i can try?

ps. I am using Xampp to host it

Comment: Disable both firewalls and antiviruses and try again, if it works, then you know where to fix things...

Comment: Also make sure to disable the firewall of your router/modem... BUT.... Don't forget to activate it later again, when you're done

Comment: Also check to which address you are binding your server (if you bind it only to localhost it won't be accessible through a network IP); check the documentation of the webserver about configuration.

Comment: More specifically: bind the server on your internal IP address, don't bind on the localhost (127.0.0.1 / localhost).

Comment: @SJuan76 How can i check if the right adress is bound?

Comment: @Gimby how can i do that?

Comment: To be honest port forwarding can be a nightmare depending on what router you are using, some routers needs some little extra effort to do it successfully. Usually the router manufacturer provide a manual on how to do it.

Comment: You do not need to forward a port in your router if that is only supposed to work on the same LAN.

Answer (score 0):

See if u can ping your ip address, and if you are visible on the network, if not check your network settings.

Answer (score -1):

Please try [ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com).

Simple tool to expose you localhost to the WWW. I have tried it and work perfect.

Comment: " other people **within the same LAN** ..."